# ERROR! java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: when running command maven install

Tags: java, maven

I have the following error when I execute the command `mvn install`. I have seen few posts online related to my problem but I still could not resolve my issue. The error is:

> <<< ERROR! java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.resolveContextLoader(ContextLoaderUtils.java:87)

And here is my *pom.xml* file:

```
   <!-- this file is generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mangroove.utils.MangrooveApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MangrooveWeb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <name>Mangroove appplication UI</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mangroove</groupId>
        <artifactId>mangroove-super-pom</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.0.11</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- Version properties -->
        <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
        <springVersion>3.1.1.RELEASE</springVersion>
       <mangroovedao.version>[0.0,1.0)</mangroovedao.version>
       <Project1.version>[1.20,1.21)</Project1.version>
        <Project2.version>1.0.0.98</Project2.version>
        <!-- Maven will save WAR file here -->
        <final.name>MangrooveUI</final.name>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangroove.dao</groupId>
            <artifactId>MangrooveDao</artifactId>
            <version>${mangroovedao.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangroove.dao</groupId>
            <artifactId>MangrooveDao</artifactId>
            <version>${mangroovedao.version}</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Project1 dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project1</groupId>
            <artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
            <version>${Project1.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Project2 dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project2</groupId>
            <artifactId>Project2</artifactId>
            <version>${Project2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GWT dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing/validation dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangroove</groupId>
            <artifactId>xhtmlrenderer-core-renderer</artifactId>
            <version>[8.0.1,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>1.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.23</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes><exclude>MangrooveWeb.xml</exclude></excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exploded</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- <goal>test</goal> -->
                            <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <runTarget>Main.html</runTarget>
                    <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Somehow I doubt this is related to Maven.  It's likely a busted Spring configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this task can solve 100% problem, but it is better:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

(add scope `test`)

Comment: Can you show more than error message? Try with Java version 1.8 or newer version of Spring Framework.

Comment: version shouldn't are `<version>0.0.0</version>`. Change to `<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`. All versions should has suffix `-SNAPSHOT` in development time.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be due to incompatible libraries being used. The spring version you are using may not support Java 1.7

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.0.html#new-in-3.0-intro

Try either bumping up the spring version or downgrading the java version. Also, make sure there are no libraries with 2 different versions being added implicitly causing the incompatibility. If you are using an IDE like eclipse, try the maven plugin and see the versions of all the libraries it is resolving to. Few of the libraries you are using implicitly may download different version of a dependent library causing the conflict.